# what is difference between Physical driver and virtual driver?

Tags: driver

Please anyone explain the exact differences?

While implemntin the driver code, I have facing an issue in both places.

Comment: So what is it that you _really_ want to ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will need more information for getting to the root of your issue. What exact problem you are facing. Well as per your query different types of driver details are given below.

**Physical Device Driver**: A physical device driver is a driver for a specific piece of hardware. This drivers are written by device vendor. Some of the examples are ethernet drivers, graphics drivers(intel, nvidia) etc

**Logical Device Driver**: A logical device driver is a high level abstraction of how a device behaves. The logical device driver talks to the physical device driver for you to keep you abstracted from the underlying hardware. So Logical device drivers are written by operating system vendor. some of the examples are generic drivers provided by microsoft like USB etc

**Virtual Device Driver**: Virtual device drivers are drivers which emulates a hardware device. It emulates a piece of harware, so that softwares can have illusion of accessing real hardware. Some of the virtual device driver examples are virtual network adapter, virtual DVD/CD drive, virtual disk device etc